# When is a quotient by closed equivalence relation Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

Let us say for an arbitrary topological space $X$ that it has property $\dagger$ if for any closed equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ (closed as a subset of $X^2$), the quotient space $X/{\sim}$ is Hausdorff.

> Is there a more "intrinsic" characterisation of property $\dagger$ (in terms of separation axioms of some sort, perhaps)?

<s>I believe compact (possibly non-Hausdorff) spaces have $\dagger$, as in their case for a closed $\sim$, the quotient map is closed, and consequently the product $X^2\to (X/{\sim})^2$ is also closed (and sends $\sim$ to the diagonal).</s>

On the other hand, it is easy to see that if $X$ is Hausdorff and has this property, then it must be normal: otherwise the equivalence relation that identifies all points in two supposedly inseparable closed sets (separately) and leaves all others untouched will be closed will have a non-Hausdorff quotient.

(As a side note, this is true for arbitrary (not neccessarily Hausdorff) topological groups if we restrict $\sim$ to be the relation of lying in the same coset of a subgroup, because the quotient map is open in this case.)

---

**Edit**: I've been looking for some references about group actions and stumbled upon a "Lemma" in Duistermat and Kolk's "Lie groups" book which states that $M/{\sim}$ is Hausdorff iff $\sim$ is closed. This is not true (as shown by the above example in a non-$T_4$ space) and I believe I see the mistake made by the authors (they seem to have assumed that the quotient mapping is open), but it has reminded me of this question (about which I'm still curious).

Comment: Closed equivalence? You mean the quotient is $T1$?

Comment: Is a closed equivalence relation one where $\sim \subset X^2$ is closed? Or one where the quotient map is a closed continuous function?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: one where ${\sim}\subseteq X^2$ is closed. The quotient is trivially $T_1$ (actually, it's enough for classes of $\sim$ to be closed for that). It is also trivially Hausdorff if we assume that the quotient map is closed (or open). The point is, if $X/{\sim}$ is Hausdorff, then $\sim$ is obviously closed, but the converse is not always true.

Comment: @user2345215: I'm not sure what you're asking about, but perhaps my previous comment answers your question.

Comment: @tomasz If $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff, then $q^2: X^2 \rightarrow (X/\sim)^2$ is continuous, and $(q^2)^{-1}[\Delta_{X/\sim}] = \sim$, which is indeed closed in that case.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Yes, as I have said, if the quotient is Hausdorff, then $\sim$ is obviously closed. I'm asking about the converse.

Comment: I was just convincing myself that indeed for the quotient to be Hausdorff at all, we need at least a closed equivalence relation. And if $\sim$ is closed, isn't $q$ always a closed map?

Comment: @tomasz I wasn't sure what closedness meant, so I thought it was that the eq. classes are closed in the quotient topology (as points, meaning it's T1). So thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @tomasz The product of two closed maps need not be a closed map. You seem to assume this in your remarks on compact spaces, though.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Good point. I forgot that the image of intersection is not intersection of images. Why would $q$ be a closed map if $\sim$ is closed? I can show it for compact $X$ using the fact that projection along a compact set is closed, but for general $X$, I don't see any reason for that.

Comment: @tomasz If $\sim$ is closed, why are all classes closed?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Because $f\colon X\to X\times X$, $x\mapsto (x_0,x)$ is continuous (and a homeomorphism onto its image). The preimage of $\sim$ by this function is the class of $x_0$.

Comment: One problem is that it is relatively easy for a non-Hausdorff space to satisfy the condition, because there are relatively few closed equivalence relations. A closed equivalence relation needs to be closed yet contain the non-closed diagonal. If $X$ is hyperconnected (like the classical $T_1$-non-$T_2$-example of the cofinite topology on an infinite set) then there are no non-trivial such relations: the closure of the diagonal is $X\times X$.

Comment: @Justpassingby: if there was a nice description under the additional assumption that $X$ is Hausdorff, that would still be somewhat interesting. But that's a good point. Usually, when we consider irreducible spaces, we don't put the product topology on the product. ;-)

Comment: Compact Hausdorff spaces satisfy this property, let me know if you want to see a proof. I doubt there is an easy "if and only if" condition for general regular (Hausdorff) spaces.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Sure! If you have a (not terribly convoluted) proof, I would be interested in seeing it. I haven't thought about this case in particular recently, but I don't recall seeing a proof (in my mind or elsewhere), so it will likely be illuminating. About the general condition, well, I very much doubt it now, too. When I was writing the question up, I was just beginning to work with the idea.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: then again, if you have a source for this, that would be even better (I might want to cite it in a paper, and it makes more sense to cite another paper or a book with the original result rather than a se post).

Comment: If you just want a reference, it is "Decompositions of manifolds",  1st chapter, including exercises in the end. www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/daverman.pdf

Comment: @MoisheCohen: Thanks, I will look into that.

Comment: @tomasz: See Exercise 4 in Chapter 1 of Daverman's book, where you replace a "closed equivalence relation" (as in your question) with an "usc decomposition". I did not have time to think about a solution of this exercise though.

Answer (score 5):

**Theorem.** Suppose that $X$ is a compact metrizable space and $R$ is a closed equivalence relation on $X$. Then $X/R$ is also Hausdorff (in fact, even metrizable).

Proof. I will need the following definition:

**Definition.** The equivalence relation $R$ on a topological space $X$ is *usc* (upper semicontinuous) if every $R$-equivalence class $[x]\subset X$ is compact and for every $R$-equivalence class $[x]\subset X$ and every (open) neighborhood $U$ of $[x]$ in $X$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $[x]$ in $X$ such that whenever an $R$-equivalence class $[y]\subset X$ has nonempty intersection with $V$, then $[y]\subset U$.

Here is how to think of this condition in the case when $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space: First of all, each equivalence class should be closed in $X$. Secondly, for every sequence $[y_n]$ of equivalence classes in $X$, if $d_{min}([x], [y_n])$ converges to zero, then $d_{max}([x],[y_n])$ also converges to zero.

Here
$$
d_{min}([x],[y])=\min \{d(x',y'): x'\in [x], y'\in [y]\}
$$
and
$$
d_{max}([x],[y])=\max \{ \max_{x'\in [x]} d(x', [y]),  \max_{y'\in [y]} d(y', [x])\}, 
$$
the latter is also known as the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#:%7E:text=The%20Hausdorff%20distance%20is%20the,point%20in%20the%20other%20set.) between $[x]$ and $[y]$.

The relevant results are Propositions 1 and 2 on page 13 in

Robert J. Daverman, "Decompositions of manifolds."
Reprint of the 1986 original. AMS Chelsea Publishing, Providence, RI, 2007.

which state that  if $X$ is Hausdorff (resp. metrizable) and $R$ is usc, then $X/R$ is also Hausdorff  (resp. metrizable).

[I can add a proof of Proposition 1 since it is an elementary exercise, but Proposition 2 is too long.]

Note that if $X$ is compact and $R$ is closed, then every $R$-equivalence class in $X$ is also closed, hence, compact. It remains to show:

**Lemma.** If $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space, then every closed equivalence relation $R$ on $X$ is usc.

Proof. Let $[x]$ be an $R$-equivalence class in $X$, and $U\subset X$ its neighborhood. I will consider a sequence $V_n$ of open metric neighborhoods of $[x]$:
$$
V_n= \{z\in X: d(z, [x])< 1/n\}. 
$$
Here $d(z,A)=\inf \{d(z,a): a\in A\}$.

Suppose that for each $n$, there exists an $R$-equivalence class $[y_n]$ such that $y_n\in  V_n$ and $[y_n]\cap X\setminus U \ne \emptyset$. Then we find $y'_n\in [y_n]$ such that
$y'\in K=X\setminus U$; $K$ is a compact subset. Then, after passing to a subsequence, $(y_n)$ converges to some $y\in [x]$ while $(y'_n)$ converges to some $y'\in K$. Since $K\cap [x]=\emptyset$, it follows that $(y,y')\notin R$. At the same time, $\lim_n (y_n,y'_n)= (y,y')$ and $(y_n, y'_n)\in R$. This contradicts the assumption that $R$ is closed.

Thus, there exists $n$ such that $V=V_n$ has the property that whenever $[y]\cap V\ne \emptyset$, $[y]\subset U$. Hence, $R$ is usc. **qed**

Combining the lemma with Propositions 1 and 2, we conclude the proof of the theorem. **qed**

Comment: This is indeed a very interesting result!  In case it has not appeared in print, it would be nice to publish it!  Otherwise, are you aware of a reference?

Comment: @Ruy: No, I do not know such a reference, but I would be surprised if it did not appear somewhere. By itself, this result is too insignificant for a publication. If you want to refer to it, just reference this MSE answer.

Comment: @Ruy The Hausdorff case is theorem 3.2.11 in Engelking's General topology, named Alexandroff theorem. The metrizable case is theorem 4.2.13 (in fact slightly stronger).

Answer (score 2):

$\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$**There is no separation condition which will do the job.** That's a vague statement, so here is a precise one: There is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which (equipped with the subspace topology) does not have condition $\dagger$.

**Proof:** Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, neither of which contains $0$. (For example, $\mathbb{Q} +\sqrt{2}$ and $\mathbb{Q}+\sqrt{3}$.) Let 
$$X = (A \times \RR_{\geq 0}) \cup (B \times \RR_{\leq 0}) \cup (\{0\} \times \RR_{\neq 0}) \subset \RR^2.$$
Define $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ to be equivalent if $x_1=x_2$ and, in the case that $x_1=x_2=0$, that $y_1$ and $y_2$ have the same sign.

**Verification that this is a closed equivalence relation:** $X^2$ is a metric space, so we can check closure on sequence. Let suppose we have a sequence $(x_n, y_n) \sim (x'_n, y'_n)$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=x$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n=y$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} x'_n=x'$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} y'_n=y'$. We must verify that $(x,y) \sim (x',y')$. First of all, we have $x_n = x'_n$, so $x=x'$ and, if $x=x' \neq 0$, we are done. If $x=x'=0$, we must verify that $y$ and $y'$ have the same sign. But $y_n$ and $y'_n$ weakly have the same sign for all $n$, so they can't approach limits with different signs.

**Verification that $X/{\sim}$ is not Hausdorff:** We claim that no pairs of open sets in $X/{\sim}$ separates the images of $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$. Suppose such open sets exist, and let $U$ and $V$ be their preimages in $X$. Then there is some $\delta$ such that $(A \cap (-\delta, \delta) )\times \RR_{\geq 0} \subset U$ and $(B \cap (-\delta, \delta) )\times \RR_{\geq 0} \subset B$. Then $U \cap \RR \times \{ 0 \}$ is an open set which contains $(-\delta, \delta)$. By the density of $B$, there must be a point of $B \cap (- \delta, \delta)$ in $U \cap \RR$, and then this gives an intersection between $U$ and $V$.

Comment: That's a nice example, thanks! In hindisght, I should have seen it coming, some sort of compactness/completeness condition is definitely necessary. Otherwise, I wouldn't be surprised if we could prove the following abstraction of your example: if $X$ is any topological space and $E$ is an equivalence relation such that $X/E$ is not Hausdorff, then there is some $X_0\subseteq X$ such that $E$ restricted to $X_0$ is closed and $X_0/E$ is still not Hausdorff.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer thanks,  I encountered this same problem .. but how does one come up with construction of such an example ?