# Rank-$1$ map $\mathbb{T}^2\to N$ factorizes as $\mathbb{S}^1\to N$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

The following fact is used in a proof of Preissman's theorem.

Let $f:\mathbb{T}^2\to N$ be a smooth map from the 2-torus to a manifold $N$. Suppose that
$d_xf:T_x\mathbb{T}^2\to T_{f(x)}N$ has rank 1 everywhere.
Then we would like to show that $f$ factorizes through a map $g:\mathbb{S}^1\to N$.

*My attempt:*

Now clearly, being of rank 1, $d_xf$ induces a  never vanishing vector field $X$(after endowing the torus with a metric).
My intuition suggest to show that  $X$ is gradient of a map  $h:\mathbb{T}^2\to \mathbb{S}^1$ (notice that  this would imply that  since $\nabla h \neq 0$, $h$ is a submersion and provides a fibration $S\to \mathbb{T}^2\to \mathbb{S}^1$.
The fiber $S$ must be $1$-dimensional and closed, thus is $\mathbb{S}^1$).
At this point we would have a fibration where $f$ is constant along the fiber of $h$ and we could pass $f$ to the quotient.
The problem is then: *how to show that $h$ exists?* note that we would not be happy with a map to $\mathbb{R}$ (also it would be impossible to have that because of the homotopy type of the torus).

Comment: [Related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203118/factoring-constant-rank-maps-into-a-submersion-and-an-immersion) It seems that compactness of the domain is crucial.

Comment: Now, combine the above link reference with my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024423/when-is-a-quotient-by-closed-equivalence-relation-hausdorff/4271589#4271589); you'll also need to prove that the equivalence relation is closed, which is not hard.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks